# How to add another image on footer.php

Tags: footer

I am new to the world of web design and my knowledge is very minimal, beginner type.

My website have a footer but I wanted to add another image on it. I do not see a footer widget. However, I did find the footer.php and it does have the code.

How can I add another image into my website's footer? I have a code but I'm not sure if I add it in the `footer.php` or `style_mod.css`.

This is the code I found on `style_mod.css`

```css
a.logoroll_img_fpds {
    background:transparent url("/wp-content/uploads/2021/03/FPDS-Logo.png ") no-repeat scroll top center / 69px 85px;   
    margin: auto;   
    opacity: .9;
    }
a.logoroll_img_fpds:hover { 
    text-decoration:none;
    opacity: 1;
}
.center-this {
    text-align:center;
}
```

Here is the code from `footer.php`

```php
<div class="logomark_nfpa"> 
            <a href="http://www.nfpa.com/" target="blank" class="logoroll_img_nfpa" href="/" alt="Member : NFPA : Visit Site" title="Member : NFPA : Visit Site"></a>                           
            </div>
```

Thank you.

Comment: `style_mod.css` is not a standard WordPress file, there's a custom CSS box in the customizer you can use for small CSS changes

Comment: Ok. I will try that. Thank you Tom!